# Cubic elliptic integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, hypergeometric-function

I search a close form about integral of  $\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x^3+a^3)\cdot (x^3+b^3)}}$ between $0$ and $+\infty$.

I know There are already a subject about this but i want a particular answer: which is the close form in terms of complete elliptic integral of the first kind $K$ ?

It seems apparently that the beginning of close form is $\frac{4 \cdot \sqrt{3}*K(X)}{(9*a*b)}$ but what is $X$ ?
I don't see the formula what i want.

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you find $\frac{4 \, \sqrt{3}\,K(X)}{(9ab)}$ ?

Comment: I experiment with MAPLE and if i put a=b and X=0,it's right.